# Disabling or Removing DiscordForOffice from Microsoft Apps

Tags: ms-word, discord, github-for-windows

I recently added DiscordForOffice in my Microsoft Apps, and I would like to disable or remove it now that I have think about it. It seems to be integrated, but I don't use Discord in my professional setting. Can anyone guide me on how to disable or completely remove DiscordForOffice from my Microsoft Apps?
https://github.com/7coil/DiscordForOffice

[image]

I already tried finding a way to remove it through options and checking the github source for any clues on how I can remove it but I really can't find it. Any assistance or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!